# Find $\mathbb{P}(X>Y)$ given the distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Random variable (X,Y) has a uniform distribution over a triangle with vertices at $(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0)$. Find $P(X>Y)$ obviously it is going to be a double integral the answer i have in my answer booklet is $\int_0^{0.5} \int_y^{1-y} 1 dxdy$. Why is that because i do not understand the logic behind it? I think i can use $y=x$ but how?

Comment: You can try by figuring out the joint probability density function -- call it $f$. Then you want to compute $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} dxdy f(x,y) \mathbb{1}_{\{x>y\}}.$

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of the situation? The line $y=x$ separates the points where $x<y$ from the points where $x>y$. This is a geometry problem.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs In fact, once the diagram has been drawn, it becomes a _counting_ problem!

Comment: OK i have the diagram but still have no idea where does the 0.5 comes from? Think need more help

Comment: mkropkowski I just put an answer, hopefully explaining the $y=0.5,$ it is the top of the subregion $x>y$.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, what do you mean, a counting problem? The triangle whose area needs calculating has uncountably many points in it. What are you thinking of?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Once the triangular region and the line $y=x$ has been drawn, it should be obvious that the region $\{X>Y\}$ has one-fourth the area of the triangle. (If not obvious, try drawing the line $y=-x$ which will divide the region into 4 congruent triangles, the $4$ being obtained by _counting_). Since the joint density is uniform, no _integration_ is needed, nor is it necessary to figure out the value of the joint pdf over the triangular region: the desired probability has value $\frac 14$.

Comment: Oh, you mean counting the congruent triangles. I see now. I certainly didn't mean to suggest, by using the word "geometry," that calculus is in any way necessary. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The triangle has area $1$ making the joint density $1,$ which explains why one integrates $1$ over the region $x>y$ inside the triangle. That region is another triangle, vertices at $(0,0),\ (1,0),\ (1/2,1/2).$ The simplest way to set up the integral is to have $y$ go from $0$ to $1/2,$ and then the $x$ go from $x=y$ to $x=1-y,$ the latter being the equation of the side of the original triangle connecting $(1,0)$ to $(0,1).$ Hence the iterated integral set up in the answer gives the probability.

Comment: If you consider the subtriangle mentioned, and a horizontal L line cutting it, that line L will go through the subtriangle twice, once where it meets $x=y$ and again where it meets $x=1-y.$